# Example of diagonalizable $ A^ k $ when $ A $ is not diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

I'm looking for an example where $ A^ k $ is diagonalizable (but non zero ) and A is not diagonalizable.

Comment: Consider the rotation by $90$ degree in $\mathbb R^2$

Comment: $$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$ They are all gonna look like this - the Jordan normal form will have simple diagonals except for the eigenvalue $0.$

Comment: $A=\pmatrix{1&1\\ 0&1}$ over a field of characteristic $2$.

Comment: It’s just an example where $A_0^2=0$ and adding another dimension.

Comment: But  $ A^2 $ is not diagonalizable

Comment: sure it is $A^2$ is diagonal (assuming you are talking about Thomas Andrew's example)

Comment: Any invertible example ?

Comment: There are no invertible examples. All examples are of the form: $$S\begin{pmatrix}A_0&0\\0&D\end{pmatrix}S^{-1}$$ where $D$ is non-zero and diagonal, $A_0^k=0$ and $A_0$ is non-zero and in Jordan Normal Form.

Comment: How can I generalize it to all cases where $ A^k $ have eigenvectors that are not the eigenvectors of $ A $